# Смысл пословицы

Tags: лексика, семантика, пословицы

Как трактовать смысл этой пословицы?

*Пусть весеннее солнце сноху согреет, а осеннее солнце дочку греет.*

Это кабардино-черкесская пословица. Но вот толкование пословицы найти не удалось. Трактовать можно по-разному. Может, кто-нибудь знает, что именно вкладывают эти народы в эту пословицу?

P. S. Просьба не писать своё личное мнение.

Answer (score 2):

Я нашла эту пословицу вот здесь: М. Ю. Езаова. [Языковые культурные коды в лексико-семантическом поле родства кабардино-черкесского языка](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/yazykovye-kulturnye-kody-v-leksiko-semanticheskom-pole-rodstva-kabardino-cherkesskogo-yazyka/viewer).
Ничего от себя не добавляла, но, честно скажу, ничего толком и не поняла (видать, не дано...).

> **5. Природный код родства** можно выделить в языке отдельно от биоморфного (зоонимного и фитонимического), так как приведенные ниже лексемы и паремии связаны с природными явлениями: <...> На каменистой горе зерно не сеют (речь идет о происхождении человека). <...> Пусть весеннее солнце сноху согреет, а осеннее солнце дочку греет...
> Во всех паремиях, относящихся к данному коду, присутствует сравнение. Сравнение как национально специфическое выражение видения мира, как ассоциативное расчленение и соединение целостных картин мира до отдельных признаков и свойств в сознании людей различных культур и языков дает возможность реально увидеть мир, в котором живет человек...

Comment: Римма, я тоже смотрел и видел именно это (может, и Серж тоже). Вот здесь хотя бы в скобках что-то написано:  "*На каменистой горе зерно не сеют* (речь идет о происхождении человека)". А в "нашей" пословице ничего: видимо, посчитали, что и так всё понятно :)).

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, да,я русский аналог  тоже взял из этой статьи. Здесь понятно, что сравнение. Но смысл не объясняется, увы.

Answer (score 0):

Ну по логике, пусть сноха(жена сына) не депрессует весной, в период любовного настроения и чтобы с сыном у них складывались семейные отношения. А дочка пусть не хандрит осенью, чтобы там урожай был и достаток в семье и в целом подготовленность к скорой зиме и тд.

Сын и дочь априори хорошие и родители прежде всего думают о них, но счастье сына зависит от поведения его жены - снохи, а счастья дочки зависит от удачного быта в общем, чтобы дочка не знала нужды.

Ну или чтобы сноха смогла родить пока молодая детей сыну и все сложилось в плане любви в молодой период и характерами сошлись, а дочка, чтобы на старости лет не осталась в нужде и муж относился бы к ней, постаревшей, с нежностью, вниманием и любовью.